# Quartz.net can't connect to Postgres DB

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, quartz.net-3.0

Here is my config:

```
["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default",
["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_",
["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.PostgreSQLDelegate, Quartz",
["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "Npgsql",
["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = @"User ID=ttt;Password=xxx;Host=ttt.postgres;Port=5432;Database=ttt;"
```

Exception:

`Could not parse property 'dataSource' into correct data type: No writable property 'DataSource' found`

I've been trying different things for over an hour, the docs don't really help (slim on the examples front) and I've tried to dig through the Quartz.Net source but no luck :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this seems to have *fixed* it - i'm not 100% up and running but I have gotten further...

```
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "SonatribeScheduler";
 properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "instance_one";
 properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz";
 properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "10";
 properties["quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold"] = "60000";
 properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
 properties["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.StdAdoDelegate, Quartz";
 properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "false";
 properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
 properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_";
```